# CSS text align center is off

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html page which is using center aligned text.  For some reason, the top title (#pageTitle id) is off by a bit, and looks like it has some added whitespace to the left of it.  I tried to reproduce the problem here, but in the stack overflow editor, the formatting was completely wonky.  Hopefully the scripts will be able to run on your machines.  If anyone has any insight as to why this is happening I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/* center aligned vertically and horizontally*/

.totalCenter {
  position: relative !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
}


/* centered horizontally */

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* div for main page content */

#mainDiv {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.title {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/* login title */

#pageTitle {
  font-size: 65px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#tagline {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}


/* input for email/password */

.infoInput {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline-width: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/* login/register button */

.submitButton {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 223, 0);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(218, 189, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.submitButton:hover {
  background: rgb(235, 204, 0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submitButton:active {
  border: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.topBarButton {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
}

#login {
  color: black;
  background-color: gold;
}

#register {
  background-color: black;
  color: gold;
}

#logo {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="/home/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <img id="logo" src="/images/logo.png">

    <button class="topBarButton" id="register">
                Register
            </button>

    <button class="topBarButton" id="login">
                Login
            </button>
  </div>

  <div id="mainDiv" class="totalCenter">
    <h1 id="pageTitle" class="title">title</h1>
    <h2 id="tagline" class="title">page tagline</h2>

    <input class="infoInput center" placeholder="Your Email..." id="email" name="email" type="email" required />
    <button class="submitButton center">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: *one of the titles is off by a bit* <-- Which one. Always be as specific as possible.

Comment: Consider editing your question to provide a more detailed description of your problem. Descriptions like "off by a bit" and "wonky" are subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title got padding because before you move it using `left` `top` and `transform` the logo image (which have float attribute) take a place at the left.
If you remove the `top` `left` and `transform` from the `mainDiv` you will see following:
[image]
This is where this whitespace come from.
You should add an element to `clear:both` under the toolbar (see snipped below)

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* ADDED THIS*/
.clear{clear:both}
/* center aligned vertically and horizontally*/

.totalCenter {
  position: relative !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%) !important;
}


/* centered horizontally */

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* div for main page content */

#mainDiv {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.title {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


/* login title */

#pageTitle {
  font-size: 65px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#tagline {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(79, 79, 79);
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}


/* input for email/password */

.infoInput {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline-width: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}


/* login/register button */

.submitButton {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 223, 0);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgb(218, 189, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.submitButton:hover {
  background: rgb(235, 204, 0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submitButton:active {
  border: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.topBarButton {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
}

#login {
  color: black;
  background-color: gold;
}

#register {
  background-color: black;
  color: gold;
}

#logo {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="/home/style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="topbar">
    <img id="logo" src="/images/logo.png">

    <button class="topBarButton" id="register">
                Register
            </button>

    <button class="topBarButton" id="login">
                Login
            </button>
            <div class="clear"></div><!-- ADDED THIS -->
  </div>

  <div id="mainDiv" class="totalCenter">
    <h1 id="pageTitle" class="title">title</h1>
    <h2 id="tagline" class="title">page tagline</h2>

    <input class="infoInput center" placeholder="Your Email..." id="email" name="email" type="email" required />
    <button class="submitButton center">Next</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried changing what you added and it didn't fix the problem. 
 The infoInput is not what is offset, it's the pageTitle.

Comment: Sorry, just realized which titles you talking about (its hidden in your snipped) please check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to align items which makes it easier:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: 'center'; 
  justify-content: 'center'; 
}

.totalCenter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: 'center';
}
```

When you set the display property to flex of a class you can use these properties:

- `align-items` : aligns items vertically.
- `justify-content` : alings items horizontally.

Flex is really cool if you cant to know more you can check out these two articles:

- [Aligning Items in a Flex Container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: thanks for the response! I'll definitely look into that